# how to serve 2 different docs with conditional routes using include_in_schema in fastapi

Tags: fastapi

here's an example code what i wrote

```
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from route import router as users_router

app = FastAPI() #this will serve swagger docs for internal(developer) use only
app.include_router(users_router)

externalAPI = FastAPI() #this will serve docs for external(clients) use only
externalAPI.include_router(users_router)

#then mount sub application to main
app.mount("/external_API", externalAPI)
```

then now i can access to 2 different swagger docs, "/docs" and "/external_API/docs"

what i would like to do is, **i want to hide several endpoint routes from external_API/docs only
that using shared routes with /docs**

i do know, i can hide my routes with include_in_schema parameter set it to False, but i want it to be conditional, **when user connec to "/external_API/docs" , hide some routes(endpoints)
when user(developer) connect to /docs, show all the routes(endpoints)**

```
# route.py

from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get('/admin_something', include_in_schema=True)
def route_admin_use_only():
   ...

@router.get('/user_something', include_in_schema=True)
def route_public_use():
   ...
```

i tried to make custom function with root_path like this

```
def only_internal(request : Request):
    """
    when root_path is "" return True (means need to serve all the routes as visible)  
    """

    root_path = request.scope.get("root_path")
    if not root_path == "":
        return False
    return True
```

then put it on my route like as below code, but no luck so far

```
#when user connect to "/external_API/docs" hide this
@router.get('/admin_something', include_in_schema=only_internal)
def route_admin_use_only():
   ...

# but this is visible
@router.get('/user_something', include_in_schema=Depends(only_internal))
def route_public_use():
   ...
```

is there any possible way i can try?

thanks for your time in advance

Comment: I don't know about your exact question, but wouldn't it be easier to have two routers, one for internal and one for external users, and then only include the external one in `externalAPI`, but both in `app`. That would accomplish what you are after, and would also guarantee that external users can't call those endpoints (remember, excluding them from the schema doesn't make them inaccessible, which could potentially be insecure, depending on your usecase).

Comment: thanks for your time @M.O.,
i understand that is the normal case of sub application uses, but in that situation, i need to duplicate same route code for different purpose

what i want to do is, **conditionally switch include_in_schema = True or False , based on client's root_path** of connection, e.g. **A**. if client connect to /docs -> all of route's include_in_schema = True -> show all the routes in /docs
**B**. if client connect to /external_API/docs -> some of route's include_in_schema = False -> hide several routes from /external_Api/docs schema

Comment: I understand what you're asking for, and I can't think of an easy way to do that. The solution I propose accomplishes what you want, and no, you do not have to repeat any route code (note that you'd run `app.include_router` on both routers, which means that `app` has access to everything `externalAPI` has, without any code duplication).

Comment: @M.O.
i'm afraid i didn't get what you meant, so there's no way to do what i want to do yet right?

Comment: I posted my suggestion as an answer, to provide a code example. Look it over, run it, and see if it accomplishes your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not exactly the implementation you're asking for, I believe something along these lines would accomplish your goal:

```py
# route.py

from fastapi import APIRouter

public_router = APIRouter()
admin_router = APIRouter()

@admin_router.get('/admin_something')
def route_admin_use_only():
   ...

@public_router.get('/user_something')
def route_public_use():
   ...

# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
from route import admin_router, public_router

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(admin_router)
app.include_router(public_router)  # this is key

externalAPI = FastAPI()
externalAPI.include_router(public_router)

#then mount sub application to main
app.mount("/external_API", externalAPI)
```

Note that since `app` includes **both** `public_router` and `admin_router`, all of those routes will be under `/docs`, but `externalAPI` only includes `public_router`, so if you go to `/external_API/docs`, you'll only the public routes.

This has the added advantage of not just hiding your internal endpoints from the public documentation, but removing them entirely. Otherwise, someone could still explore your API and find the `/external_API/admin_something` endpoint.

Comment: thanks for your code mate!, your idea make sense to me, i will go with this idea, until fastapi have some improvement about my problem